# jQuery get image position after rotation

Tags: jquery, rotation, position, delay

I am have a javascript function that rotates a set of images like a carousel and therefor sets an absolute position for every image per update interval.

That works just fine.

When an image is clicked it is brought to the front. That might take 2-3 seconds depending on the number of images.

After that rotation is done a want to dtermine the position of the front image (css - left and top attribute values.

Problem here is that when I do it like

```
    $('.rotatableImage').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().append("<div style='position: absolute; left: " + $(this).css('left') + "; top: " + $(this).css('top') + ";'>Text</div>");
    });
```

I get the immediate position for left and top when clicked before rotation is done.

Is there a way to solve this without modifying with jquery or maybe javascript?

I also tried some SetTimeout but that also binds the click immediately and s I get the wrong values.

Comment: where is the rotation-code?

Answer (score 0):

Rotation code is here @john Smith
item is of var  Item = function(img, opt) cotaint img object attributes

```
var style;
var px = 'px';  
var context = this;

for (var i = 0; i<itemsLen ;i++)
{
   item = items[i];

   sinVal = funcSin(radians);

   scale = ((sinVal+1) * smallRange) + minScale;

   x = this.xCentre + (( (funcCos(radians) * this.xRadius) - (item.orgWidth*0.5)) * scale);
   y = this.yCentre + (( (sinVal * this.yRadius)  ) * scale);       

   if (item.imageOK)
   {
       var  img = item.image;
       w = img.width = item.orgWidth * scale;                   
       h = img.height = item.orgHeight * scale;


       img.style.left = x + px ;
       img.style.top = y + px;
       img.style.zIndex = "" + (scale *100)>>0;                                     
   }
   radians += spacing;
}

 this.innerWrapper.style.display = 'block';
```